# Isomorphism Theorems for the derived Tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $(A,m)$ be a local ring, and $\kappa=A/m$. Let $\otimes^L$ denote the derived tensor product.

So basically I want to prove $\kappa\otimes_A^L\kappa\simeq (\kappa\otimes_A^LA/f)\otimes_{A/f}^L\kappa$. I already know, that a similar statement is true for rings (e.g $B'\otimes_AC\simeq B'\otimes_B(B\otimes_A C)$).

So let $P^\ast$ be a projective resolution of $\kappa$, then $\kappa\otimes_A^L\kappa\simeq P^\ast\otimes_A \kappa\simeq (A/f\otimes_A\kappa)\otimes_{A/f}P^\ast\simeq(A/f\otimes_A\kappa)\otimes_{A/f}^L\kappa$. Now I would like to just exchange $A/f\otimes_A\kappa$ with $A/f\otimes_A^L\kappa$, but am i allowed to do so?